# radical expression foil which confuses me

Tags: linear-algebra

So straight to example

$\sqrt{x} = 3-\sqrt{x}$

When squared gives us

$x = (3-\sqrt{x})(3-\sqrt{x})$

Now foil

$x = 9 - 3\sqrt{x} - 3\sqrt{x} + ?$

I don't understand the l part of the foil what should be there . I saw some where that  $-\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x} = x$  but I dont quite get it, so please explain . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(-\sqrt{x})(-\sqrt{x}) = (-\sqrt{x})^2 = (\sqrt{x})^2 = x$.

(Note that this is *not* the same thing as $-\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x}$, which would be $-2\sqrt{x}$.)

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{x} = 3 - \sqrt{x}$.

Adding $\sqrt{x}$ to both sides:

$2\cdot \sqrt{x} = 3$, then square both sides:

$4x = 9$.

So $x = \dfrac{9}{4}$

Comment: Sorry but i am still confoused

Comment: @abdulraziq: see edit.